# Sufficent condition for which closed set in norm topology become weak* closed set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

I know that if we have convex closed set then it becomes weakly closed .

But I have not come across any such theorem in case about weak* topology

V be Banach space V* be is dual space It has 3 topology norm,weak,weak*

Under what condition closed set in norm topology in V* become weak*closed?

Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: There is the Krein-Smulian theorem: Let $C$ be a convex subset of the dual space of a Banach space $X$. Then $C$ is weak* closed if and only if $C\cap t B_X$ is weak* closed whenever $t>0$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thanks a lot Sir. Dear Sir Is it really useful to show something weak* closed we have to show $C∩tB_X$ weak* closed? Please can you tell me what is use of above theorem as it leads to more work –

Comment: One use is when $X$ is separable: then a convex set in $X^*$ is weak* closed if and only if it is weak* sequentially closed.